# Regex that tests for neighboring consonants (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex that tests whether a consonant is followed by another consonant in a string.

So "donkey" for example would return true because it contains an 'n' that is followed by a 'k'

I tried :

```
/(bcdfgjklmnpqrstvwxz)*/i.test(someword);
```

which is obviously wrong because it simply tests if any of these consonants is in the string.

I don't know what syntax I should use basically for *any 2 characters from this group of consonants that are next to each other*

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/[qwrtypsdfghjklzxcvbnm]{2,}/i.test("donkey")
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#quantifiers (scan down to the 9th row in the table)

Comment: @soktinpk That's a hugely larger set than the consonants. Did the OP really want `queue!!` to pass?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [[Character Classes]](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to solve this and not [(group constructs)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Here's a RegExp a bit more advanced, using [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make use of vowels instead of consonants:

RegEx: `/(?=[a-z]{2})[^aeiou]{2}/i`

Live demo: http://regex101.com/r/jO4hB4/1